# Send data with POST method to a PHP file using C#

Tags: c#, php, post

I'm create an app that collect some data from user's computer
 then I want to send them to a PHP file that receive data then php valid the code then it return a text and I want to show it in a text box in my application.
My questions are **how can I post data in c#** and **collect a text that php return after data valid**.
A text that php return is this format:

```
echo $validcode;
```

Comment: Basically, `WebClient.UploadData`, `UploadValues` etc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdbbwh0a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP request with post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post)

Answer (score 2):

to send PHP data over C# you can use a `NameValueCollection` which is part of the `System.Collections.Specialized`

So, you should initialize it as following:

```
NameValueCollection dataToSend=new NameValueCollection();
```

Then, for each PHP field, you should do this:

```
dataToSend['fieldname']=data;
dataToSend['fieldname2']=data2;
using(WebClient wc=new WebClient())
{
   byte[] resp=wc.UploadValues(URL,dataToSend);
}
```

fieldname and fieldname2 will be the POST variables which u will use in your PHP, for example:

C#

```
dataToSend['fieldname']=data;
using(WebClient wc=new WebClient())
{
   byte[] resp=wc.UploadValues(URL,dataToSend);
}
```

And PHP:

```
echo $_POST['fieldname'];
```

Comment: Tnx, I'm not so good at C# it throw and error in NameValueCollection "The type or namespace name 'NameValueCollection' could not be found". How can I fix it I searched in reference but there is no such NameValueCollection there.

Comment: add using system.collections.specialized to your project

Comment: Hi again! Sorry for this but I have another error :( I got error for this line: dataToSend['fieldname']=uniqueId; it said "too many characters in character literal" and in this line for using(WebClient wc=new WebClient()) said: "The type or namespace name 'WebClient' could not be found" How can I fix it?

Comment: You have to use double brackets, like dataToSend["fieldname"] and for the error related to WebClient you should add using System.Net at the begin of your project...
You should read .Net guides on microsoft site to see the full documentation, and, just saying, this question has been asked about 1 million times. Try to avoid duplicates, there's a search bar at page top, and, at last, if I helped you, please check the answer as right